# Only one type of list may be specified?

Tags: grep, pipe, cut

So I have a bash script which is below, and whenever I try to execute it, it says only one type of list may be specified, any clue as to whats wrong with this code? I interpret this as we use grep to find the word (-word) of the first character ($1) typed by the user in the file femalenames.txt and then using the cut command we print the 2nd field of characters 16-20? sort of confused there.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
grep -w $1 femalenames.txt | cut -f2 -c16-20
```

Comment: you can only use -f or -c with cut, not both..

Comment: oh, I get it, thanks for the fast response :)

Comment: @Sundeep why don't you write it as an answer?

Comment: @myrdd apart from -c/-f, the question is not clear.. does the OP want 16-20 of 2nd field? then cut cannot be used, awk/perl would be needed.. as usual, a concise sample input/output would have helped

Comment: cut can surely be used, but it needs two invocations

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe it ( | ) again & it'll work.

Command guide [here](https://linuxhint.com/bash_pipe_tutorial/)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
grep -w $1 femalenames.txt | cut -f2 | cut -c16-20
```